# Can't figure out how to include *.html files within a site-packages folder

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I cannot figure out how to write my setup.py script in order to include *.html files within the installed package.

Here is my attempt:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='django-testapp',
  version='0.1',
  author='RadiantHex',
  license='BSD',
  keywords='testapp,django',
  packages=['testapp']],
  include_package_data=True,
  data_files = os.walk('testapp'),
  zip_safe = False,
  )
```

The *.html files are contained within the testapp folder.

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following 'package_data' argument to the setup():

```
setup(...,
    package_data={
        'testapp' : ['testapp/*.html']
    }, ...)
```